# datetime datatype not working in soap php

Tags: php, xml, soap

This is my code

```
 $c = new soapclient('http://www.redbus.in/WS2/BookingService.asmx?wsdl',
     array('authentication' => array('LoginID' => 'x','Password'=>'x')));

  $timezone = new DateTimeZone('UTC');
  $time='2012-04-17T16:50:45';
  $date = new DateTime($time,$timezone);
  $sourceid=array('SourceID'=>'244','DestinationID'=>'477','DateOfJourney' =>$date);
  $stockprice = $c->GetAvailableRoutes($sourceid);

   print_r($stockprint);
```

it's not working in datetime format datatype variable

it shows error like this

Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [soap:Client] Server was unable to read request. ---> There is an error in XML document (2, 252). ---> The string '' is not a valid AllXsd value. in E:\xampplite\htdocs\index1.php:9 Stack trace: #0 [internal function]: SoapClient->__call('GetAvailableRou...', Array) #1 E:\xampplite\htdocs\index1.php(9): SoapClient->GetAvailableRoutes(Array) #2 {main} thrown in E:\xampplite\htdocs\index1.php on line 9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to [format](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php) it, otherwise you are throwing an DateTime object into your array (which PHP tries to convert to a string, which does not work)

For example:

```
$date->format('Y.m.d H:i:s');
```

Usage

```
$sourceid = array('SourceID'=>'244','DestinationID'=>'477','DateOfJourney' => $date->format('Y.m.d H:i:s'));
```

Comment: Did you try it as parameters instead of an array? And did you already try to dump the generated XML as described in [SoapClient::__getLastRequest()](http://php.net/manual/en/soapclient.getlastrequest.php) (see comments too)

Comment: when i put the datetime format it returns "Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [soap:Client] Server was unable to read request. ---> There is an error in XML document (2, 292). ---> The string '2012-04-17IST00:00:00' is not a valid AllXsd value"

Comment: That's why I said look in the comments too; you need a [try-catch block](http://www.php.net/manual/en/soapclient.getlastrequest.php#90252). --- What do you used for `format()`? That's a strange format you used (`2012-04-17...`). Do you know which format they accept? (look in the documentation of their SOAP)

Comment: i used the try catch block but no gain can u give me code format

Comment: I don't know which format is accepted. Did you use it as follows `try { $stockprice = $c->GetAvailableRoutes($sourceid); } catch(SoapFault $e) { print_r($c->__getLastRequest()); }`?

Comment: try catch not help it is same as ordinary method .I think the datetime format is wrong.The api provider provide only the datatype of DateOfJourney is DateTime() i already provide the error " The string '17-04-2012 00:00:00' is not a valid AllXsd value. "

Comment: I opened their web site and on the main page there's something like a search where they use `dd-mmm-yyyy`. So I suggest you should try this too (`$date->format('d-m-Y');`).

Comment: Ok I did some research; dateTime is SOAP specific. Please try `$date->format(DateTime::ISO8601);`

Comment: still it shows like "The string '2012-04-17T00:00:00+0530' is not a valid AllXsd value"

Comment: can you explain this error "Stack trace: #0 [internal function]: SoapClient->__call('GetAvailableRou...', Array) #1 E:\xampplite\htdocs\index1.php(15): SoapClient->GetAvailableRoutes(Array) #2 {main} thrown in...."

Comment: I'm getting desperate. Please try this: `$date->format('Y-m-d\TH:i:s')`

Comment: already i use this method but it didn't work thank you very much for cooperate with me

Comment: Sure. But this problem has to do with this. Let's try it with `date_default_timezone_set('UTC'); $date = date('c', strtotime('2012-04-17T16:50:45'));`. If this doesn't work, I give up :(

Comment: it shows like this "Object reference not set to an instance of an object. in E:\xampplite\htdocs\index1.php"

Comment: Maybe have a look [at here](http://www.php.net/manual/de/soapclient.soapclient.php#100292)

Comment: but in .net code they specify simply                        "RouteList result = bookService.GetAvailableRoutes (auth,”122”,”124”,
DateTime.Today.AddDays (1));"

Comment: yeah, try it with parameters instead of an array `$stockprint = $c->GetAvailableRoutes('244', '477', $date->format('Y-m-d\TH:i:s'));`

Comment: sorry, i dont know whats left. i'd need to test things myself

Comment: anyway thank for you co-operation still i am not getting result

Comment: I recently had this problem, and the solution was the put it in 'Y-m-d' format (no time) - and it had to actually be a string, not just an object with a __toString() method (I was using a custom date class).  If they want it like 04-03-2008, then they probably want it in either d-m-y or m-d-Y format, both of which are rather strange formats.  Try both.

Answer (score 11):

I had a similar problem when using a SOAP service from PHP. I fixed it using:

`$date->format('c');`

(ISO 8601 date, added in PHP 5, looks like: 2004-02-12T15:19:21+00:00)

Comment: thanks, it worked in the soap request for me on php 5.5 and on server api.mindbodyonline.com

Comment: Thanks, I had a same problem in soap request and now it works

Comment: This helped me when making a Soap Call to Ontime360's api