# How to create Date format in Nusoap server side?

Tags: php, nusoap

I make a simple web service using nusoap & php for server. In that server page I want to instanciate Date object and return it to the client. It will be part of a complextype (struct). I read some solutions about soapval() function but I can not make it work.
So how can I return date?

```
//ComplexLoginType
$server->wsdl->addComplexType('UserInfo','complexType','struct','all','',
    array( 
    'Id' => array('name' => 'Id','type' => 'xsd:int'),
    'LastName' => array('name' => 'LastName','type' => 'xsd:string'),
    'FirstName' => array('name' => 'FirstName','type' => 'xsd:string'),
    'Address' => array('name' => 'Address','type' => 'xsd:string'),
    'Position' => array('name' => 'Position','type' => 'xsd:string'),
    'Manager' => array('name' => 'Manager','type' => 'xsd:int'),
    'Password' => array('name' => 'Password','type' => 'xsd:string'),
    'Date' => array('name' => 'Date','type' => 'xsd:string'))
);
```

My usage of soapval();

```
$Date = new soapval('Token', 'dateTime', '2006-12-19T19:51:12.174Z');
```

Comment: Check it please, may be it help for you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10172403/datetime-datatype-not-working-in-soap-php

Comment: It's about sending date format to server. I want to create date format in server side not in client side.

Answer (score 3):

In my service with nusoap this code is working

```
$server->wsdl->addComplexType( 
    'order_type',
    'complexType',
    'array',
    'sequence',
    '',
    array(
        ...
        'date_trips' => array('name' => 'date_trips', 'type' => 'xsd:date'),
        ...
    )
);
```

And service takes date in `YYYY-mm-dd` format.